# Conspicuous Marker Not Affecting Anything Else

Tags: marginpar

I want to mark some points in my text with a highly visible symbol and yellow background color without affecting other typesetting.  The idea is that there are certain points in my text that I have to pay attention to in a future edit (or edition).  I don't want to insert text, because it changes the typesetting of the remaining text.  Moreover, I do not want to overplot main text (with the yellow background), because I still want to be able to read the underlying paragraph --- I want something somewhat transparent.  `\marginpar` seems to be designed for something like this, but it doesn't work in a float, and I may want to use my hint even inside a `\marginpar`.  Worse, I am colorblind, so I need my hints with a fencepost, like yellow background text.  Right now, I am inserting text, which obviously does change the actual text and to make it a big and visible hint, it needs to be a big and visible text.  :-(

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\UPDATETODO}{{\huge\hl{$\bullet$}}}

\begin{document}

\marginpar{ABC \UPDATETODO H}%
I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. \UPDATETODO I do want to mark this. \begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,10){\UPDATETODO}\end{picture} I do want to mark this, too.  I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. I do not want to mark this. 

\begin{table}
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
  \caption{A Table}

  I do not want to mark this. \UPDATETODO I do want to mark this.

  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I've tried but can't help. I think TeX has a macro for typesetting text that takes up no space but I can't find it. Also tried marking via a math superscript but to no avail. I'm also colour blind and have been watching the BETFRED World Snooker Championship; I was very pleased when one of the main contenders asked the referee to point out the brown ball nestled among the reds as he couldn't tell the difference. He might possibly go on to be the World Champion in spite of what people may think of his disability. I think of it as a bonus as I am not allowed any household colour decisions.

Comment: I've worked more on this but with no success (I thought that TeX's `rlap` macro might help but it didn't seem to help in your situation). It seems to me that you are after a macro that will typeset its argument, taking up no space in the final document, while being printed semi-transparently over anything else that might be below it. A big ask! Have you thought of the `todo` package or similar?

Comment: Hi Peter---I did not know of these packages.  It turns out that `todonotes.sty` does not do the job (fails in floats), but Fabian Lipp's (2020) `luatodonotes.sty` works!  mille grazie.  do you want to post the answer and me accept it?

Comment: I tend to use stuff based upon the marginnote package. It works everywhere at the cost of not moving the text if they collide in the margin. This is also why I don't use the todonotes package (it uses marginpar), I tend to use fixme reconfigured to use marginnote (it's a conf option).

Comment: @ivoWelch Following your comment I have added an answer. But thinking about it, if you are willing, I think that you could give a better answer by showing how you have used `luatodonotes` to produce the typeset result that you were after. Perhaps I should delete my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rambling answer based on the comments to the original question.

I've worked more on this but with no success (I thought that TeX's `\rlap` macro might help but it didn't seem to help in your situation). It seems to me that you are after a macro that will typeset its argument, taking up no space in the final document, while being printed semi-transparently over anything else that might be below it. A big ask! Have you thought of the `todo` package or similar? –

The OP responded

Hi Peter---I did not know of these packages. It turns out that `todonotes.sty` does not do the job (fails in floats), but Fabian Lipp's (2020) `luatodonotes.sty` works! mille grazie.

The answer then, is the `luatodonotes` package --- please read the documentation (normally via `texdoc luatodonotes`).